# $f=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n):X\longrightarrow Y_1\times Y_2\times\cdots \times Y_n$ is continuous $\iff f_i$ is continuous for all $i$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I have the following question for HW:

> > let $(X,d)$ and $(Y_i,d_i)$ be metric spaces for each $1\leq i\leq n$.
> >
> > Suppose that for each $1\leq i\leq n$, $f_i :X\longrightarrow Y_i$ is given.
> >
> > Prove that $f=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n):X\longrightarrow Y_1\times Y_2\times\cdots \times Y_n$ is continuous $\iff$
> >
> > $f_i$ is continuous for all $i$

I don't understand if the writer of this question omitted the metric on $Y_1\times Y_2\times\cdots \times Y_n$

on purpose or is it because all the metrics on this product space are equivalent

(it's just a guess, I didn't check it)

please help clarify this. Thanks!

btw I don't want the proof of this claim. just want to understand it.

Comment: You're right that the question writer should specify what the metric is on the product space. There are several natural ways to define a metric on a product of metric spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric), which all give equivalent topologies; but there are lots of inequivalent metrics as well. Probably the simplest product metrics to work with are the max of the individual metrics or the sum of the individual metrics. (Indeed, in this problem, one of these might be better for one direction of the if-and-only-if, and the other better for the other direction!)

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! do you have an example for a metric on this product such that this claim fails?

Comment: Sure, just choose some metric that doesn't have anything to do with anything, like the discrete metric on the product space.

Answer (score 0):

Just so that this has an answer, I summarize what Greg Martin commented: the question writer should have specified the metric. It is not true that all metrics on product spaces are equivalent.